# Strange behavior of android's ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

When I try to simulate configuration change in my app by enabling "Don't keep activities" in developer options every time I leave an activity and return, the `ViewModel` is recreated! Aren't `ViewModels` supposed to handle these situations?

I can handle this problem by saving my activity's state in `onSaveInstanceState` but then what's the point of using a `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> When I try to simulate configuration change in my app by enabling "Don't keep activities" in developer options every time I leave an activity and return, the ViewModel is recreated!

AFAIK, "don't keep activities" destroys activities when you navigate away from them. It does not simulate configuration changes.

On Android 8.1, the setting specifically states: "Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it".

> Aren't ViewModels supposed to handle these situations?

The `ViewModel` system handles configuration changes. It does not handle activities being destroyed or processes being terminated.

To simulate a configuration change, change the configuration. For example, you could rotate the screen or change your locale.

> I can handle this problem by saving my activity's state in onSaveInstanceState

Anything that can go into the saved instance state `Bundle` should go into the saved instance state `Bundle`, as that handles both configuration changes and process termination.

> what's the point of using a ViewModel?

`ViewModel` is there for things that cannot go into the saved instance state `Bundle`, such as:

- Big things (`Bitmap` of a photo)
- Live things (`LiveData`, RxJava `Observable`, etc.)
- Wrongly-typed things (you cannot put a `Socket` in a `Bundle`)
- Things that are not really part of the "instance state" and should not be needed in case Android terminates the process, but you would like to have them around for a simple configuration change
- And so on

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found this link very useful: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: "AFAIK, 'don't keep activities' destroys activities when you navigate away from them. It does not simulate configuration changes."

The onDestroy method of an Activity is called in both the cases, Configuration change and "Don't keep activities" action. Then what is the difference here?

Comment: @ashwinmahajan: A configuration change recreates the activity and retains things like viewmodels. An activity being destroyed does neither of those things.

Comment: does the behavior when opening intent camera (that our activity will be destroyed-recreated) because android will free memory, was not means for ViewModel? @CommonsWare or does we really need to use room as persistence data?

Comment: well what @Mostafa provides from official docs, that's not possible using ViewModel. It is indeed need to use persistance data storage

Comment: @mochadwi: Correct. `ViewModel` is purely held in RAM. When your process gets terminated, your `ViewModel` goes away, along with the rest of your objects. The saved instance state `Bundle` (or `SavedStateHandle` with newer versions of the `ViewModel` library) can help with short-term process termination scenarios like yours. Otherwise, save the data to files, databases, etc.